# Django + DRF: User schedule availability

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, schedule

I'm building an API where I need return to users events with a timestamp within in their available time. Since this is an API I don't need a front-side, I will receive a json in backend, but I am not clear about which data should I receive. User should be able to mark a schedule as monthly, weekly, etc. or just for one day. I have found projects like this one [django-scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler) but I don't know if it will fits my needs. Any advice?

Comment: So what is your question? Seems like you are shopping for libraries which is really outside of scope of SO questions. Please feel free to expand the question with concrete code issues.

Comment: Actually at this point I don't have code issues, because I don't know how to face this functionality. I was asking for experiences or ideas about it.